# How to run Crystal Reports with SQL Database Application on Client Machine

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

I've a developed a **desktop application** with **SQL Server DB**. In d**evelopment machine, SQL Server was running with (local)**. I need to add **Crystal Reports** in my application which should be working on client.

Here, question is **what is needed to be on client machine to run successfully my application with database**. Remember, **on client side there is no SQL Server installed.**

Help me in this regard.

Comment: Just note: you dont need to bold a lot of words like this

Comment: Is your desktop application pulling the data from the DB or is crystal Reports?  What format is the data comming in?

Comment: @Quinma: Data is in DB and Application uses Crystal Reports to display Data from DB.

Answer (score 0):

In the case crystal is supposed to connect to the Database you will need to set up a connection in your OS to the database. You can use ODBC or some such with sql server 2008 driver.

Also, you will have to set up the report to use the SQL driver.

Comment: Its working on my machine, I'm talking about the Client machine. How can I setup connection of DB and Crystal Reports there. So, what should be added in pre-req to install and work smoothly for application.